# Dictionary of Parent Class from Wrapper Class using Child Classes

Tags: c#

I have some strategies like the following:

```
public abstract class AbstractDoSomeStuffStrategy
{
    public abstract string DoMySpecificFoo(string necessaryParameter);

    public abstract string DoMySpecificBar(string necessaryParameter);
}

public class AmazingConcreteStrategy : AbstractDoSomeStuffStrategy
{
    public override string DoMySpecificFoo(string necessaryParameter)
    {
        return "Amazing concrete foo! Have a " + necessaryParameter;
    }

    public override string DoMySpecificBar(string necessaryParameter)
    {
        return "Amazing concrete bar! Have a " + necessaryParameter;
    }
}

public class SubparConcreteStrategy : AbstractDoSomeStuffStrategy
{
    public override string DoMySpecificBar(string necessaryParameter)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override string DoMySpecificFoo(string necessaryParameter)
    {
        return "Meh. Whatever. This foo is garbage so take your " + necessaryParameter + " back.";
    }
}
```

And a wrapper like the following:

```
public class StrategyWrapper<T> where T : AbstractDoSomeStuffStrategy
{
    public T MyStrategy { get; set; }

    public StrategyWrapper()
    {
        MyStrategy = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
    }
}
```

And am attempting to use the wrapper like the following:

```
public class SomeController
{
    private Dictionary<string, StrategyWrapper<AbstractDoSomeStuffStrategy>> _strategyMap { get; set; }
    public SomeController()
    {
        _strategyMap = new Dictionary<string, StrategyWrapper<AbstractDoSomeStuffStrategy>>();
        _strategyMap.Add("AmazingConcrete", new StrategyWrapper<AmazingConcreteStrategy>());
        _strategyMap.Add("SubparConcrete", new StrategyWrapper<SubparConcreteStrategy>());
    }

    public AbstractDoSomeStuffStrategy GetStrategy(string name)
    {
        return _strategyMap[name].MyStrategy;
    }   
}
```

In an attempt to execute something like the following:

```
namespace ShamelessSOQuestions
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            AbstractDoSomeStuffStrategy myStrategy;
            var controller = new SomeController();
            myStrategy = controller.GetStrategy("AmazingConcrete");

            Console.WriteLine(myStrategy.DoMySpecificFoo("woohoo"));
        }
    }
}
```

However, at my controller, it doesn't like my `_strategyMap.Add(...StrategyWrapper<AnythingOtherThanDoSomeStuffStrategy>)`

1. I know it's not possible in this way, but I'd like it to be or I'd like to fix it to where something similar is achievable.
2. I know I could rip out the StrategyWrappper and instantiate the individual strategies in the dictionary. That seems like a lot of waste though for potential non-use (especially if those strategies actually have some complex constructor).

Clearly I'm going about this in all the wrong way. Can someone please help me understand how to make this work to where I can have the type safety all around but still make it pretty flexible?

Comment: have you tried using an interface for `AnythingOtherThanDoSomeStuffStrategy`?

Comment: For that to you you'd need to use a co-variant interface.